# How to create different page footer depending on a condition?

Tags: jasper-reports, footer

I have a requirement to show different footer depending on a condition.

My footer consists of many static labels and theoretically I can define a 'Print When Expression' for each of the labels. But it is inconvenient.

**Q:** Is it possible to select a different footer depending on a condition?

If not how else can I handle such situation without having to specify the condition in many places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [xsd](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/dtds/jasperreport.xsd#L36) allows none or maximum **one** `pageFooter` tag with a maximum of [**one**](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/dtds/jasperreport.xsd#L1850) band.

***but***

This is a typical example where you can use the [frame component](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/using-frames), to group your data and decide if to display it.

**Example** displaying different frame with text fields depending on page number

```
<pageFooter>
    <band height="60" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="540" height="60" uuid="d0198e94-8325-4909-9804-a8d393600ec5">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}%2!=0]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="379e2ac0-63ea-4493-bd38-1b7ca7b35d8c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field 1"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="6598ba79-08b6-4997-953d-70b64f159e3b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field 2"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="540" height="60" uuid="d0198e94-8325-4909-9804-a8d393600ec5">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}%2==0]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="379e2ac0-63ea-4493-bd38-1b7ca7b35d8c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field 3"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="6598ba79-08b6-4997-953d-70b64f159e3b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field 4"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

add the different text of the different pageFooter's to different frame's, then set printWhenExpression on the frame component.